# Grails 2.3.4 Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-orm

We have grails  application ruining in tomcat 7.0.30.
Grails version was 2.2.4, and it was running very stable during last year.
I Tried to switch grails version to 2.3.4, On test environment it was acting normal(no any issues).
But when I put it on production after 20 minutes I start getting following exceptions

```
[ajp-bio-9009-exec-430] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000].. Stacktrace follows:
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [ajp-bio-9009-exec-430] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
        at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria$_count_closure4.doCall(DetachedCriteria.groovy:686)
        at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria$_withPopulatedQuery_closure10.doCall(DetachedCriteria.groovy:931)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_withDatastoreSession_closure20.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:680)
        at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withDatastoreSession(GormStaticApi.groovy:679)
        at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.withPopulatedQuery(DetachedCriteria.groovy:913)
        at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.count(DetachedCriteria.groovy:684)
        at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.count(DetachedCriteria.groovy:683)
        at com.webbfontaine.wftaglib.BeanDataLoadController.doLoadData(BeanDataLoadController.groovy:30)
        at com.webbfontaine.wftaglib.BeanDataLoadController$_closure1.doCall(BeanDataLoadController.groovy:14)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at org.josso.tc70.agent.SSOAgentValve.invoke(SSOAgentValve.java:684)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

In our application all queries to DB are done via Grails GORM, we do not use any SQL or HQL query.

My guess is that something is wrong in grails 2.3.4 itself (some connections are not closed / returned to pool correctly).

Am i missing something or its grails issue ?
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

Grails 2.3.x [replaced Commons DBCP with Tomcat JDBC](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7455), that may be the reason for the difference in your application. You can check for differences in the pool configuration.

Comment: Thanks for answer Sérgio. I'd like to check it with grails 2.3.x and "Commons DBCP". Do you know how to force grails to use "Commons DBCP" ?

Comment: I think you will need to do something like this [doWithSpring](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-jdbc-pool/blob/master/JdbcPoolGrailsPlugin.groovy#L15), changing the classname of the dataSource bean.

Answer (score 5):

There are [a few bugs in Grails in dataSource default settings](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11097). These problems will be fixed in Grails 2.3.6 .

Here's an example of optimized dataSource settings for MySQL

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    properties {
       // Documentation for Tomcat JDBC Pool
       // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes
       // https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration.html
       jmxEnabled = true
       initialSize = 5
       maxActive = 50
       minIdle = 5
       maxIdle = 25
       maxWait = 10000
       maxAge = 10 * 60000
       timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
       minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
       validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
       validationQueryTimeout = 3
       validationInterval = 15000
       testOnBorrow = true
       testWhileIdle = true
       testOnReturn = false
       ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad = true
       // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JDBC_interceptors
       jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
       defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED // safe default
       // controls for leaked connections 
       abandonWhenPercentageFull = 100 // settings are active only when pool is full
       removeAbandonedTimeout = 120
       removeAbandoned = true
       // use JMX console to change this setting at runtime
       logAbandoned = false // causes stacktrace recording overhead, use only for debugging
       // JDBC driver properties
       // Mysql as example
       dbProperties {
           // Mysql specific driver properties
           // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
           // let Tomcat JDBC Pool handle reconnecting
           autoReconnect=false
           // truncation behaviour 
           jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
           // mysql 0-date conversion
           zeroDateTimeBehavior='convertToNull'
           // Tomcat JDBC Pool's StatementCache is used instead, so disable mysql driver's cache
           cachePrepStmts=false
           cacheCallableStmts=false
           // Tomcat JDBC Pool's StatementFinalizer keeps track
           dontTrackOpenResources=true
           // performance optimization: reduce number of SQLExceptions thrown in mysql driver code
           holdResultsOpenOverStatementClose=true
           // enable MySQL query cache - using server prep stmts will disable query caching
           useServerPrepStmts=false
           // metadata caching
           cacheServerConfiguration=true
           cacheResultSetMetadata=true
           metadataCacheSize=100
           // timeouts for TCP/IP
           connectTimeout=15000
           socketTimeout=120000
           // timer tuning (disable)
           maintainTimeStats=false
           enableQueryTimeouts=false
           // misc tuning
           noDatetimeStringSync=true
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The dbProperties config will be fixed for 2.3.6, otherwise these settings work for previous 2.3.x versions

Comment: Hibernate4 (4.3.1 version) has problems with Tomcat JDBC Pool interceptors: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11151 . Remove "StatementCache(max=200)" when Hibernate 4.3.1 is used. The problem will be fixed in Hibernate 4.3.2 (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8853)

Answer (score 2):

I would first check if there are threads that are "stuck" and hold a db connection. You can see this from a JVM threaddump.

You can do a thread dump in unix by sending a SIGQUIT (3) signal to the Java process PID.
You can use the "kill -3 PID" command to do this.  The threaddump goes to stdout (which goes to catalina.out on tomcat by default). It won't terminate the Java process so you can normally use this method in production environments.

Another way to get the threaddump is to use the "jstack PID" command.

Usually it's worth doing a few subsequent dumps a few seconds a part. This way you can diff the dumps to see what changes and what stays the same. You usually have to do diffing manually.